# How sharp are Wolverine's claws?

Tags: marvel, wolverine, x-men-origins-wolverine

Say you have a steel knife cutting through wood. The strength of the steel in the knife means it breaks wood and not the other way around, but it does not guarantee that it will go all the way through. You'd need a considerable amount of force to slice a piece of wood with a knife.

Now let's apply that to the claws:

- When Wolverine cut that sink in half in *X-Men: Origins* he barely pressed that deeply into it.
- When he cuts into a car while riding away from the barn he doesn't get thrown off the bike but instead there is a clean cut along the side of the car.

Comment: I think maybe a more appropriate question might be along the lines of: Is there anything Wolverine's claws have difficulty cutting through?

Comment: No. That is not what I want to know. It's easier to answer, but not what I'm looking for

Comment: I think (though citation definately needed) it was stated wolverines claws are self sharpening and so probably vary in sharpness.

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly recurring belief that in addition to being functionally indestructible, his claws have a mono-molecular edge. Such an edge (at least in comic-book science) is so sharp that it slices between the molecules of anything it comes in contact with, and being indestructible, they'd never lose that edge.

So not as much strength is needed to hack through something in such a scenario.

Comment: "fairly recurring belief" As in a fan theory, or...?

Comment: Can you reference a source please

Comment: Yes, mostly a fan theory, but one that fits the facts at hand. The TVTrope in question is Absurdly Sharp Blade - a knife or weapon that seems to be able to cut things that simple physics should prevent.  The effects on the materials described in the question are far closer to that of something cut with something super-sharp, as opposed to hacked through by sheer strength. Here's a good Nerdist video about the math of the sharpness. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f-lO2s-5aBM